# Threading, and why my program seems to get stuck in a single method

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I am trying to learn some network programming, so I thought a good place to start would be with sockets and how to use them. Although it seems that I have hit a brick wall, but the issue does not have as much to do with sockets as it does with checking a socket for two things at (seemingly)the same time.

```
    package com.redab.server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class server implements Runnable {

    private final int portNumber = 4444;

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket clientSocket;

    private Thread thread;

    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private BufferedReader stdIn;

    private String incomingText;
    private String outgoingText;

    private Boolean isRunning = false;

    public server() {
        thread = new Thread(this, "serverThread");
        try {

            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // Unless socket connection is made, probram will not proceed beyond this line.
            System.out.println("connected");
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to listen on port " + portNumber + " or listening for a connection");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private synchronized void start() {
        thread.start();

        isRunning = true;
    }

    private synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            isRunning = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("running...");

        while (isRunning) {
            incoming();
            outgoing();
        }
    }

    private synchronized void incoming() {
        System.out.println("Incoming");
        try {
            if ((incomingText = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(incomingText);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private synchronized void outgoing() {
        System.out.println("outgoing");
        try {
            if ((outgoingText = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println("Server: " + outgoingText);
                System.out.println("Server: " + outgoingText);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        server server = new server();

        server.start();

    }

}
```

My problem is the following:
How do I make it so both the method incoming() and outgoing() is ran constantly when I execute the code? 
I did google a bit and threads seems to be the solution, so I tried creating a thread which is supposed to run both methods for me. But I run into the same problem again, the code gets stuck in the incoming() method when I want it to simply check this statement `((incomingText = in.readLine()) != null)` and then proceed to the method outgoing(). I suspect I might need two threads, one of which checks for incoming messages through the socket and the other checks for outgoing messages that are typed into the console`(System.in)`.

Comment: You need two threads if you want receive/transmit to happen at the same time.

Comment: Building on what @JimGarrison said:  Each thread in your program should wait for _one_ thing.  Examples would be, a thread that waits for incoming network connections, a thread that reads from an established network connection, a thread that waits for console input or for keyboard and mouse events, or a worker-pool thread that waits for tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect I might need two threads, one of which checks for incoming messages through the socket and the other checks for outgoing messages that are typed into the console(System.in)

You are right, you need two threads, one per each task.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to check if there is data available to read by using the `in.ready()` method first. If available, you can read the data using `in.readLine()`, else do nothing. Currently, `in.readLine()` blocks because there is no input available on the socket.

Comment: While true, this doesn't really address the OP's issue.  What do you do if `in.ready()` is false? Go into a hard polling loop until something _does_ come in?  Two threads are required.

Comment: I tried this, it works. If in.ready() is false it simply moves on back up to the `while(isRunning)` loop that is in the run function, exactly like I want it too. However this isn't to say that having two threads is a bad idea, I just haven't figured out how to create to threads and make them complete seperate tasks.

Comment: @JimGarrison, do you mind reverting your downvote, as I actually addressed the OP's issue?

Comment: No, because that approach results in a hard polling loop that sits there consuming 100% cpu.

Comment: @JimGarrison, how will an if statement with `in.ready()` go in a hard polling loop, if nothing is done if it is false?